# Nested for loop not incrementing in the Selenium Automation script practice

Tags: java, selenium, for-loop, selenium-webdriver

There's a website with a div, containing 7 items, when one item is added to cart there is a new popup regarding continue shopping or checkout. Need to automate, Add all the 7 items one by one while clicking Continue shopping over the pop.

I tried this with nested For Loops, but looks like nested for loop variable "j" not incrementing.

Currently, for the first item, works as expected, but for the rest of the items, just the first loop's mouse hover action is performed.

Also please instruct if any better methods than my method, much appreciated.

Code:

```
        import java.time.Duration;
        import java.util.List;
        import org.openqa.selenium.By;
        import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
        import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
        import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
        import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
        import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
        import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class DressShop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:/Java with Lan/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));

        driver.get("http://automationpractice.com/index.php");

        List<WebElement> offers = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#homefeatured li"));
        List<WebElement> addCarts = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@id='homefeatured']/li/div/div[2]/div[2]/a[1]"));

        Actions a = new Actions(driver);
        for (int i = 0; i < offers.size(); i++) {

            WebElement offer = offers.get(i);
            a.moveToElement(offer).build().perform();

            for (int j = 0; j == i; j++) {
                WebElement addCart = addCarts.get(j);
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(addCart));
                a.moveToElement(addCart).click().build().perform();
                WebElement closePop = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@title='Continue shopping']"));
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(closePop));
                a.moveToElement(closePop).click().build().perform();

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need nested loop for this type of scenarios.

You can collect all the link

```
//ul[@id='homefeatured']//li
```

using this xpath, now iterate over the list and hover the mouse to each product and click on add to cart and then continue shopping.

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:/Java with Lan/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30));
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://automationpractice.com/index.php");
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    List<WebElement> allLinks = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@id='homefeatured']//li"));
    for (WebElement link : allLinks) {
        action.moveToElement(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(link))).pause(3).build().perform();
        WebElement addToCart = link.findElement(By.xpath(".//descendant::div[@class='right-block']//descendant::a[@title='Add to cart']"));
        action.moveToElement(addToCart).pause(2).click().build().perform();
        //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//descendant::div[@class='right-block']//descendant::a[@title='Add to cart']")));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[@title='Continue shopping']"))).click();
    }
```

Comment: This should work with Selenium4. if you are using Selenium 3 then use this line instead `wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);`

Comment: Yea bro actually got the understanding now, nested loop was useless, i guess i was thinking too much :)
Sorry for any inconvenience. Thanks for help